# Detect objects in an area of interest

Tags: c#, image-processing

I want to detect the rectangles in the red zone of the picture below, I defined the picture center and drew a line and compared my center to the rectangles center and that way I am able to find the centres.

My approach didn't take Y into consideration but the left range requires that. So I think Points would be appropriate to use here but I don't know how to do that,

QUESTION How to define this range(demonstrated by the redlines), I just want to know which objects are on the left line,right line,center line(gray lines), So by defining lines,spaces, anything would work for me,

```
   // Rectangles am interested in, have left, right, top, bottom pixel position
  var rectangleCenter =(left + right) / 2; 

if (rectangleCenter >= (CenterRef - 50) && rectangleCenter <= (CenterRef + 50)) 
{
}

// assuming 5 is the curve
for(int i=0; i<somelimit; i+5)
{ 
var rectangleCenter = (left + right) / 2;

// assuming its a 1000 pixel image, Mycenter is 500,
leftRef = MyCenter + 250;         
leftRef + i;

if (rectangleCenter >= (leftRef - 50) && rectangleCenter <= (leftRef + 50))         
{
}
```

[image: Problem Demonstration]

Comment: would you mind explain more! and please highlight the are you want to detect in the picture (I'm sorry but I cannot understand clear, sorry :( )

Comment: The red lines is my region of interest, I want to detect rectangles that are within them

Comment: so you want to detects lines(black)? or rectangles that would happened with these lines?

Comment: I just want the rectangles, the grey lines are in the picture,

Comment: With the information provided, this is unsolvable. Just by analysing the picture you uploaded, it would be necessary to know the exact geometry of the red lines (start/end coords, inclination, length). Also you would have to know the location and dimensions (bottom/top/left/right values) for each single rectangle. If the geometries you are expecting are more or less similar to the one in the picture, it might be relatively easy. Otherwise (red lines located anyywhere) might become pretty complex. Could you please provide more information?

Comment: But those redlines do not exist they're representing the range, for instance, I defined the center range based on the center+-50 pixels. And yes the rectangles are available therefore, I just mentioned that they're given so we can assume left,right,top,bottom exist, it's pretty straight forward like the picture, coz there are no more givens except the rectangle positions and the image center.

Comment: so do you mean detect like this [picture](http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2201-287.html)

Comment: @user2511414 I am only interested in knowing, this rectangle is to my left,right,center. So if you any other detection its fine

Comment: so if the target images are simple drawing like you provide, it's not going to be to much hard

Comment: show me an example please,adjust my solution, how would you go about it ? I want to know which objects fall within that area(gray lines area)

Comment: What you have to do is comparing the X/Y values (4 points define each) for each rectangle with the references you want. If you say that the lines do not exist, the calculations wouldn't be too accurate anyway. Tell me if this is OK and I will write a quick code for you to perform this actions: dividing the picture into 4 main areas (left-bottom, left-top, right-bottom and right-top) and determining in which ares are the rectangles located. Is this OK for you?

Comment: You have to understand that it is possible detect anything but that you have to provide the data defining the given framework. Determining whether the rectangles fall within the red lines or not is impossible without having the exact geometry of these lines (or, at least, an approximation).

Comment: well, its an image that's not processed, so there's only an estimation of the geometry of these lines, how do I estimate that ? can you elaborate a solution of how you would estimate them too

Comment: Can I define the picture into 3 curved areas ? the 3 red rectangles in this case ?

Comment: (sorry I was doing something else) if the shown geometry is constant for all the cases (the red lines are always located in the same positions), it is definetively possible to create something more or less reliable. Is this the case?

Comment: the geometry is constant as in yes, they will always appear in the same shape, different sizes,locations. pretty much like the picture. So we have one outside all bounds now in this picture, could have more in others, so on

Comment: Let me work on a quick approach to help you to define the problem better. Will come back in a while.

Comment: am eager and very interested to find how didn't i see that simple solution

Comment: ?! Simple? No, it is not simple. I said a quick help for you to deal with the program by your own; I am just building the framework of the algorithm. Do you want it or not?

Comment: yes I want any help ! please !

Comment: appreciate your help very much too, you are just the right guy to help with this based on your profile :)

Comment: Wait a bit. I am on it. As said, this is not simple but at least will give you some indication to face this problem. Write you back as soon as I have it. (PS: regarding your last comment, my profile is not too good lately, too many down-votes :))

Comment: Well... I have finished. Finally, I decided to go a bit more in detailed than what I was planning; also bear in mind that the required (trigonometrical) calculations are not in place, but well... I hope that you will not complain. The main idea is having everything properly structure and reduce the whole problem to small sub-problems; thus, just follow the indications and intend to understand each bit properly. I think that it is pretty clear though.

Comment: I will be leaving in brief. Any question? (bear in mind that I have fixed a couple of small bugs in the code).

Comment: have been out of that since ages ! just one more question, what do you recommend me to read,keywords for performing trigonometrical calculculations ? In my head its using the 4 points,angle to draw the shape and see if the 4 points (allPoints) of the rectangle falls within ? or is this not the approach ? recommended reading ? – TrackmeifYouCan 10 secs ago edit

Comment: You don't know anything about trigonometry? You have to check whether the given lines surround the given point, that is, if at the Y value of the given point, their X values are, respectively, smaller and bigger. But to perform this calculation you have to know a bit of trigonometry; if not perhaps you should ask someone to help you. The problem is quite-well defined and you have all the required information (more than enough because, as said, the angles are redundant). Show the problem to someone with a basic geometry knowledge and should do it.

Comment: And I have to go now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double[,] allPoints = new double[5, 3]; //Each rectangle is defined by 4 X/Y Points (left-top, left-bottom, right-top and right-bottom)

        //The four points of each rectangle have to be inside the given area (inside the given couple of red lines)
        int foundInArea = 0;
        int areaCount = 0;
        do
        {
            areaCount = areaCount + 1; //There are three areas; what is inside each couple of two red lines

            foundInArea = areaCount;
            int count1 = 0;
            do
            {
                count1 = count1 + 1;
                if (!isInArea(areaCount, new double[] { 0, allPoints[count1, 1], allPoints[count1, 2] }))
                {
                    foundInArea = 0;
                    break;
                }
            } while (count1 < 4);

            if (foundInArea > 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (areaCount < 3);

        if (foundInArea > 0)
        {
            //Rectangle inside are foundInArea
        }
    }

    private bool isInArea(int areaNo, double[] pointToTest)
    {
        bool isThere = false;

        double alpha = returnAngles(areaNo); //Inclination of the red lines
        double[] startPoint1 = returnStartEndPoints(areaNo, true, true); //Initial point of the red line on the left
        double[] endPoint1 = returnStartEndPoints(areaNo, true, false); //End point of the red line on the left
        double[] startPoint2 = returnStartEndPoints(areaNo, false, true); //Initial point of the red line on the right
        double[] endPoint2 = returnStartEndPoints(areaNo, false, false); //End point of the red line on the right

        return checkPoint(pointToTest, alpha, startPoint1, endPoint1, startPoint2, endPoint2);
    }

    private bool checkPoint(double[] pointToTest, double alpha, double[] startPoint1, double[] endPoint1, double[] startPoint2, double[] endPoint2)
    {
        bool isThere = false;

        //You have all the information and can perform the required trigonometrical calculculations to determine whether the two lines surround the given point or not
        //I think that I have worked more than enough in this code :)

        return isThere;
    }

    //Hardcoded angles for each red line. 
    //All the angles have to be taken from the same reference point (for example: middle-bottom part)
    //Example: area1 (lines on the left): 240 degree, area2: 270 degree... 
    private double returnAngles(int areaNo)
    {
        double outVal = 0;
        if (areaNo == 1)
        {
            //outVal = val;
        }
        else if (areaNo == 2)
        {
            //outVal = val;
        }
        else if (areaNo == 3)
        {
            //outVal = val;
        }

        return outVal;
    }
    //Returning the X (index 1) and Y (index 2) values under the given conditions (start/end point for each area)
    //These values have to be hardcoded from a rough estimation. For example, by assuming that the start is in the upper part,
    //the starting point for the left line can be assumed to be X = max_X/3 and Y = max_Y
    private double[] returnStartEndPoints(int areaNo, bool isLeftLine, bool isStartPoint)
    {
        double[] outPoint = new double[3];

        if (areaNo == 1)
        {
            if (isLeftLine)
            {
                if (isStartPoint)
                {
                    //outPoint[1] = value; //hardcoded X for start point of line on the left of area1
                    //outPoint[2] = value; //hardcoded Y for start point of line on the left of area1
                }
                else
                {
                    //outPoint[1] = value; 
                    //outPoint[2] = value;  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (isStartPoint)
                {
                    //outPoint[1] = value;
                    //outPoint[2] = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    //outPoint[1] = value; 
                    //outPoint[2] = value;  
                }
            }
        }
        else if (areaNo == 2)
        {
            if (isLeftLine)
            {
                if (isStartPoint)
                {
                    //outPoint[1] = value; 
                    //outPoint[2] = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    //outPoint[1] = value; 
                    //outPoint[2] = value;  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (isStartPoint)
                {
                    //outPoint[1] = value;
                    //outPoint[2] = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    //outPoint[1] = value; 
                    //outPoint[2] = value;  
                }
            }
        }
        else if (areaNo == 3)
        {
            if (isLeftLine)
            {
                if (isStartPoint)
                {
                    //outPoint[1] = value; 
                    //outPoint[2] = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    //outPoint[1] = value; 
                    //outPoint[2] = value;  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (isStartPoint)
                {
                    //outPoint[1] = value;
                    //outPoint[2] = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    //outPoint[1] = value; 
                    //outPoint[2] = value;  
                }
            }
        }

        return outPoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Am gonna read this, and hope your here few minutes later if I notice anything, that was very helpful regardless !!

Comment: As you can see, there you have a place for everything: the lower part you have where you can hardcode all the required points (returnAngles and returnStartEndPoints). In Form1_Load you have to introduce the 4 points defining each rectangle and checkPoint is where all the calcs have to be done (I didn't anything).

Comment: I am sure that it is helpful: this is the main framework to account for this problem (under the current geometry or any other one). I thought that you didn't have the ideas too clear and thus I preferred to spend a bit on giving you a proper help (although I wasn't planning to spend so much). I did it relatively quickly; thus if you see a bug or anything, just overlook it :)   I will be here for a whie but not for too long.

Comment: your amazing man, that was very helpful indeed ! its my first geometrical problem sort of speak

Comment: No problem. If you have any doubt (but a short one :) have already spent pretty much on this). I will answer it tomorrow. Just a last thing I realised now: the angles are not even required (are implicit in the start/end points of the lines) and thus you can comment these parts.

Comment: nice, thats very helpfull too,I also can see that its possible to draw the rectangle without the angle pretty much, I am overwhelmed !